# Equations with square roots of polynomial

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p_1(x), ..., p_n(x)$ be some univariate polynomials with integer coefficients.
Let $Q(y_1, ..., y_n)$ be a multivariate polynomial with integer coefficients.
Clearly $Q(\sqrt{p_1(x)}, ..., \sqrt{p_n(x)}) = 0$ has solutions,
and the solutions are very likely algebraic numbers.

My question is, Are the solutions actually algebraic numbers?
If yes, Is there an existing algorithm that computes the min-poly of those numbers?
Does the same hold for any equation synthesized
using integers, addition, multiplication, square roots?
(For instance $\sqrt{7x^2 + \sqrt{5 + x^4}} + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{3x^3 + 2x^5}} = 0$)

Comment: I'm not sure about minimal, but the product over all sign variants in $Q(\pm\sqrt{p_1(x)}, ..., \pm\sqrt{p_n(x)})$ is a polynomial in $x$ that has all the roots of the original expression as roots.

Comment: I think it's not always true that $Q$ has roots. Take $Q(y_1,y_2)=y_1-y_2 +1$ and $p_1(x)=p_2(x)$, for example.

Comment: Thank you both.  I now have an answer to what I really had in mind.  Do either of you care to write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let me denote the algebraic closure
of the rationals $\mathbb Q$ as $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.
I will also denote the algebraic closure
of the polynomial ring $\mathbb Q[x]$ as $\overline{\mathbb Q[x]}$.
We call an element of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ an *algebraic number*,
and an element of $\overline{\mathbb Q[x]}$ an *algebraic polynomial*.
(I am not aware of a common name for algebraic polynomial;
please let me know if there is any.)

Then here is the claim.

> Pick any nonzero algebraic polynomial
> $F(x) \in \overline{\mathbb Q[x]}$,
> This $F(x)$ is treated as a function
> from $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$
> (we are going to have some branching issues here but let me ignore),
> the solutions of the equation
> $$ F(x) = 0 $$
> are all algebraic numbers.

Sketch of Proof.
$F(x)$ must satisfy some (minimal) equation
with coefficients in $\mathbb Q[x]$.
In particular, the constant term, $C(x)$,
of that equation is in $\mathbb Q[x]$.
But the constant term is a product of $F(x)$ and
the conjugates of $F(x)$ under some Galois actions.
So any $x$ that satisfies $F(x) = 0$ must also satisfies $C(x) = 0$.
So $x$ is an algebraic number defined by
polynomial $C(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$.

Remark 1: the sketch given above is inspired by Lutz Lehmann's idea
that one can multiply all conjugates together.

Remark 2: the sketch given above addresses Arix94's comment
in the following sense:  If the constant term $C(x)$
is actually a degree-$0$ polynomial in $x$
(that is, it is a rational number rather than an interesting polynomial),
then there is no solution $x$ by the fundamental theorem.